# parse a url, get hash value, append to and redirect URL

Tags: php

I have a PHP foreach loop which is getting an array of data.  One particular array is a href.  In my echo statement, I'm appending the particular href onto my next page like this:

```
echo '<a href="nextpage.php?url='.stats.'">Stats</a>'
```

It redirects to my next page and I can get the URL by $_GET.  Problem is I want to get the value after the # in the appended URL.  For example, the URL on the next page looks like this:

```
stats.php?url=basket-planet.com/ru/results/ukraine/?date=2013-03-17#game-2919
```

What I want to do is to be able to get the #game-2919 in javascript or jQuery on the first page, append it to the URL and go to the stats.php page.  Is this even possible?  I know I can't get the value after # in PHP because it's not sent server side.  Is there a workaround for this?

Here's what I'm thinking:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick="stats('.$stats.');">Stats</a>';

<script type="text/javascript">
  function stats(url){
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    alert (hash);
  }
```

But that's not working, I get no alert so I can't even try to AJAX and redirect to the next page.  Thanks in advance.

Update: This is my entire index.php page.

```
<?php
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://basket-planet.com/ru/');
foreach ($html->find('div[class=games] div[class=games-1] div[class=game]') as $games){
  $stats = $games->children(5)->href;
  echo '<table?
          <tr><td>
            <a href="stats.php?url=http://www.basket-planet.com'.$stats.'">Stats</a>
          </td></tr>
        </table>';
        }
?>
```

My stats.php page:

```
<?php include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = $_GET['url'];
//$hash = $_GET['hash'];
$html = file_get_html(''.$url.'');
$stats = $html->find('div[class=fullStats]', 3);
    //$stats = $html->find('div[class='.$hash.']');
echo $stats;
?>
```

What I want to be able to do is add the hash to the URL that is passed on to stats.php.  There isn't much code because I'm using Simple HTML DOM parser.  I want to be able to use that hash from the stats.php URL to look through the URL which is passed.  Hope that helps...

Comment: That code of yours is wrong in so many levels. By the way, you never made clear what was the hash value alerted

Comment: This is completely a client-side problem. Drop the PHP, show your actual HTML output and work from there.

Comment: I don't see how AJAX is involved here? You have a link on one page, the user clicks it and it takes them to another page... and then what?

Comment: @Alexander the hash value in the URL corresponds to a table which will be parsed on the next page.

Comment: @Diodeus I can't drop the PHP because that's how I'm getting the hrefs.

Comment: @tcovo My thinking behind AJAX was a way to pass the value to the next page, the stats.php page.  From there I could get the hash value and find the table which is located on basket-planet.com/ru/results/ukraine/?date=2013-03-17#game-2919

Comment: I'm not sure you understand what AJAX is used for. It is used for transferring data between the client and the server, separately from the process of the browser initially loading a webpage. In this case, you are transferring data from the client to the client. The second page's javascript can access the information in window.location.hash, so where do you see AJAX (a javascript-initiated client-server transaction) fitting in?

Comment: It's just something I was thinking about using.  I knew it was probably wrong but maybe there was a way of doing it.  So there is no way of doing what I want?  On my second page I can get the hash but there is no way to get it into PHP on my second page?

Comment: if you want a piece of data to be available in PHP, you could put it in a query parameter.

Comment: Why are you passing in a `url` parameter to the `stats` function if you don't use the value in that function? This makes no sense.

Comment: @ErikE  I need to use the URL and the hash for different things.  The URL itself I will GET and use it to parse that URL page.  The hash I need to find the table inside that URL page.

Comment: @tcovo can you give me an example of what you mean "put it in a query parameter"?

Comment: I'm sorry but this just makes no sense, yet. We need a **full example** with filled-in values for each step you are trying to accomplish. Without that, we're just playing guessing games. Which is not what we're here to do.

Comment: `echo '<a href="nextpage.php?gameId='.gameId.'&url='.stats.'">Stats</a>'` you will need to make the gameId variable and populate it with the hash part of `stats` (do some string manipulation in PHP). Then you use `$_GET['gameId'];` on the next page.

Comment: maybe try `echo '<a href="nextpage.php?url='.urlencode(stats).'">Stats</a>'` also

Comment: Yeah, urlencode helps pass the entire href but my problem is getting that # part out.  And also, I can't manipulate the URL because there is no URL until the user picks which one he wants.  Am I making sense?  So I can't manipulate it BEFORE the user clicks on it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use urlencode in PHP when you generate the HREFs so that the hash part doesn't get discarded by the browser when the user clicks the link:

index.php:

```
<?php
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://basket-planet.com/ru/');

echo '<table>';
foreach ($html->find('div[class=games] div[class=games-1] div[class=game]') as $games){
  $stats = $games->children(5)->href;
  echo '<tr><td>
            <a href="stats.php?url=http://www.basket-planet.com'.urlencode($stats).'">Stats</a>
          </td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Then on the second page, [parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) the hash part out of the url.

stats.php:

```
<?php
include_once ('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = $_GET['url'];
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
$hash = $parsed_url['fragment'];

$html = file_get_html(''.$url.'');
//$stats = $html->find('div[class=fullStats]', 3);
$stats = $html->find('div[class='.$hash.']');
echo $stats;
?>
```

Comment: Worked...thanks!  Why the F did I see so many other examples where people said it's impossible to get the hash in PHP?  Anyway, sorry for the headache, thanks for your help!

Comment: It's impossible to get the hash in PHP when a user clicks a simple link with a hash, because the browser doesn't send that part in the request. But in this case, we have a link with query parameters, and one parameter happens to contain a URL. The `url` query parameter is encoded so that the browser won't interpret it as part of the actual URL, and so it gets passed intact to PHP as a query parameter, and from there we can do whatever we want with it in PHP.

Comment: ooooohhhhh...appreciate the explanation.  I'll remember this for future references.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function stats(url)
{

  window.location.hash = url.substring(url.indexOf("#") + 1)

  document.location.href = window.location

}
```

If your current URL is `index.php#test` and you call `stats('test.php#index')` it will redirect you to `index.php#index`.

Or if you want to add the current URL's hash to a custom URL:

```
function stats(url)
{
  document.location.href = url + window.location.hash
}
```

If your current URL is `index.php#test` and you call `stats('stats.php')` it will redirect you to `stats.php#test`.

To your comment:

```
function stats(url)
{

  var parts = url.split('#')

  return parts[0] + (-1 === parts[0].indexOf('?') ? '?' : '&') + 'hash=' + parts[1] 

}

// stats.php?hash=test
alert(stats('stats.php#test'))

// stats.php?example&hash=test
alert(stats('stats.php?example#test'))
```

Comment: My current URL is index.php.  I want my next page to be "stats.php?url=basket-planet.com/ru/results/ukraine/?date=2013-03-17#game-2919?hash=game-2919".  When the user gets redirected to the stats.php page, I want that to be in the URL.  Reason why I was thinking of AJAX is to send the URL and hash as two different data sets.  But I don't think that's possible because I would need to send back a response with AJAX, the user will not get redirected when they click initially.

Comment: And the hash you wanted added to `stats.php` is the hash that's currently set on `index.php`?

Comment: I updated the question with the full code.  No, the hash is part of the href which the user clicks on which is generated from the foreach loop.

Comment: So you want the hash to be re-added as a GET variable?

Comment: I want the hash to be added to the URL which gets appended to stats.php?url=....&hash=...

Comment: tcovo's solution got me the right answer.  Thanks for the advice.